# How to Reschedule Quartz trigger?

Tags: java

I am trying to learn quartz. I have main method

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SchedulerException {

        try {
            JobDetail job1 = JobBuilder.newJob(Job1.class).withIdentity("job1", "group1").build();

            Trigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("cronTrigger1", "group1")
                    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.weeklyOnDayAndHourAndMinute(3, 12, 38)).build();

            Scheduler scheduler1 = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            scheduler1.start();
            scheduler1.scheduleJob(job1, trigger1);

     scheduler1.shutdown();
    }

        catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Which works fine. It prints to the console on 3rd day of the week at 12:38 pm. 
Now, what I want to do is to reschedule the trigger, so that it deletes the previous stored trigger and creates a new trigger with new schedule.

I read a lot of things at a lot of places but I just can't seem to understand clearly what I actually have to do, for ex:

```java
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    Trigger newTigger = what ever you want;
    Trigger oldTrigger = context.getTrigger()
    Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
    scheduler.rescheduleJob(oldTrigger.getKey(), newTrigger);
    }
```

- tell the scheduler to remove the old trigger with the given key, and 
  put the new one in its place*

*but I can't understand the approach(I do understand what is happening in the code though). Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Do you have access to the scheduler in the context of the application to reschedule the job?

Comment: Yes he can access the scheduler like this: context.getScheduler(); But I think he wants a full source code solution for this task. Also I think this is quite interesting: https://coderanch.com/t/658823/java/Reschedule-quartz-trigger Same question with exactly same sentences was asked on coderanch 3 years ago.